# Python - Create a DataFrame by feeding a string file properly formatted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's take this example:
`df = pd.DataFrame([["0.06308", "1291"], ["0.06346", "1990"]])` which works perfectly fine and generates the 2x2 dataframe

Now, I have a string variable (let's call it mystring) formatted exactly like this: `[["0.06308", "1291"], ["0.06346", "1990"]]`
I am trying to run this code: `df= pd.DataFrame(mystring)` and I get error:

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may transform your string into a python a list, as it's formatted as JSON, you can load it using the `json` lib

```
import json

s = '[["0.06308", "1291"], ["0.06346", "1990"]]'
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(s))
```

You could use `ast.literal_eval` too

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = '[["0.06308", "1291"], ["0.06346", "1990"]]'
df = pd.DataFrame(literal_eval(s))
```

Comment: @George You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Comment: Hmmm...something's wrong with this, I already accepted the answer. Hope it works now.

Comment: Hmmm...something's wrong with this, I already accepted the answer hours ago. I did it again now. Hope it is fine. I am new around here, so still learning how this platform works. Many thanks for your help!